# How can I pass an id to route in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm new with Django. Started learning it for 4 days now. I have an issue and I don't know how to solve it. I've searched high and low on Google, but I couldn't understand much from the solutions provided. Here is the issue:

1. I've created models and views for the app
2. I've created the database with all tables needed. In them I have 2 foreign keys which link between two tables
3. In the html, I need to show only the information linked to the foreign key.(eg. I have a webpage in which I have all the countries. When I click on Argentina, I want only Argentina's provinces to be shown)
4. Where and what do I need to do in order for it?

Again, I've searched high and low on Google, because I don't think is something that complicated. But everything I found didn't solve my request.

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: No. Just plain SQLite with Django

Comment: Please post your code snippet